# How to retrieve information from website(first login using POST and cookies) using windows 7 desktop widget

Tags: javascript, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

I need to build a Win 7 desktop widget, that would display a single value from a certain web page. To view the page you need to login first(with POST form), get session id, and proceed to the page. Then i'll download it and parse, no problem here. I also probably need cookies support for this. So, are there any tools for this in the Windows 7 gadgets engine(POST, cookies)?